# Dynamic templateUrl by using attrs in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

We are currently using the code labeled **#2** but want to use the code labeled **#1** and would like to confirm if there would be any negative side impacts or issues.

```
// #1
<my-thumb my-type="'type01'"></my-thumb>
=> templateUrl: 'components/thumb.type01.tpl.html'


In Controller
=> this.type = 'type02';

<my-thumb my-type="type"></my-thumb>
=> templateUrl: 'components/thumb.type02.tpl.html'

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------

// #2
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  $templateRequest('components/thumb/thumb.' + (scope.type || 'file') + '.tpl.html')
    .then(function (html) {
      elem.append($compile(angular.element(html))(scope));
      _link (scope, elem, attrs);
    });
}
...
function _link (scope, elem, attrs) { ... }
```

#### we don't want to use 'ng-include' because of meaningless tag.

```
ex) 
<my-thumb my-type="type">
  <div ng-include="components/thumb.type01.tpl.html">
    ...
  </div>
</my-thumb>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditions on your `templateUrl` just like this :

```
app.directive('myThumb', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
        if (attrs.type === 'type01') {
          return 'components/thumb.type01.tpl.html';
        } else if (attrs.type === 'type02'){
          return 'components/thumb.type02.tpl.html';
        }
      },
      ...
    };
  });
```

Comment: let me clarify. type is prop of object. I need value not key itself. For example, in <my-thumb my-type="item.type">...</my-thumb> I exptected that value of my-type will be "image, file, etc" but it is "item.type". I wanna get the values not prop name itself.